# How do I add a custom search filter to my method?

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I am writing a macro that involves taking .csv files from folders. The macro asks the user to enter the folder path and when entered, it will take all the .csv files in the folder and make them sheets in the workbook.

I want the macro to ask the user what extension they want to load into the workbook.

For example, some files are named Chan_41-103.csv, Chan_41-109.csv, and Chan_44-103.csv. So if there is a way to ask the user what files they want and they could enter "*-103.csv" and the macro would only take the files with -103.csv in the file name.

I know I could directly hard code  "*-103.csv" and it would do that but, there are a lot of files with different names and I would have to run this macro for a bunch of files. If it can ask the user, that would be great.

Here is the code I already have:

```
Sub CSV_Sheets()
'This takes the .csv file from a specific folder and puts it into the workbook
Dim i As Integer
Dim path As String
Dim Extension As String

Cells(2, 2).Value = InputBox("Extension of File:", "Extension *-#.csv")
Extension = Cells(2, 2).Value & "\"
i = 1
Range("A1").Value = "CSV Folder Path="
Range("A1").HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
Cells(1, 2).Value = InputBox("CSV File Folder Pathway:", "Path Assignment")
path = Cells(1, 2).Value & "\"
Filename = Dir(path & Extension)
Do While Filename <> ""
Workbooks.Open Filename:=path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Next Sheet
Workbooks(Filename).Close
Filename = Dir()
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Use the `InputBox` command.

Comment: I have the InputBox command in there already, just want to know how to link what I enter into the input box and the extension so in the line "Filename = Dir(path & Extension) I want whatever I put in the input box to be in the place of Extension.

Comment: Did you try putting a `*` in front of `Extension`?

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub test()

Dim FolderPath As String
Dim xlwb As Excel.Workbook
Dim Filename As String
Dim path As String


 FolderPath = "PathToYourFolder"

 path = FolderPath & "\*" & InputBox("Enter the Extension here.", "Extension Retrieval") & ".csv"

 Filename = Dir(path)

 If Filename = "" Then

 ElseIf Filename <> "" Then
    Set xlwb = Excel.Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & "\" & Filename)
 End If

End Sub
```

An asterisk serves as a wildcard, I tested this with a file named test-104.csv and it worked like a charm